# How can I use proper object-oriented models in CodeIgniter with constructors?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

The way I create CodeIgniter models at the moment is (i.e. no constructor, having to pass userID all the time and limited to one object):

```
$this->load->model('User');
$this->user->set_password($userID, $password);
```

But I would like to do it like this:

```
$this->load->model('User');
$User = new User($userID);
$User->set_password($password);
```

**UPDATE:** Perhaps just a user model was a poor example.

For instance, if I have a shopping list that has various items I would like to use PHP in this way:

```
$this->load->model('List');
$this->load->model('Item');

$List = new List();
$items[] = new Item($itemName1, $itemPrice1);
$items[] = new Item($itemName2, $itemPrice2);

$List->add_items($items);
```

CodeIgniter feels fundamentally broken in handling PHP OO in this way. Does anyone have any solutions that can still use the superobject within every model?

Comment: Do you just favor using the new operator?

Comment: Codeigniter use one big superobject called CI. I don't think be a good idea add new objects to that framework. In any case they should be inherit from him.

Comment: I'd like to be able to store objects in other objects

Comment: You are not supposed to use the `load->` function for every instance of every object in CI. It's only for application-level items. Nothing prevents you from creating your own object (library or model) and using `require_once` to make them available, then instantiating/using them however you wish. If you need access to the CI object, you can get it from anywhere by doing `$CI =& get_instance();`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it like you normally would:

```
require_once(APPPATH.'models/User.php');
$User = new User($userID);
```

Or, you can rely on a table-level model to return a record-level model:

```
$this->load->model('users_model'); // users (plural) is the table-level model
$User = $this->users_model->get_user($userID);
```

Meanwhile, in `users_model`

```
require_once(APPPATH.'models/User.php');

public function get_user($userID)
{
  // get a record from the db
  // map record to model
  // return model
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `subclass` the model or just add something in the `constructor`
I think you need to adjust code to do it the way you're looking to…